# Can't boot UEFI on 22.04 - drops to initramfs prompt (can't find /dev/sdaX)

Tags: boot, uefi, boot-repair

sda1 holds `/boot/efi/EFI/`, sda3 holds Ubuntu system, sda4 holds `/var`, sda6 holds `/home`.
From the initramfs> prompt I'd like to know the commands to boot the system.  Trying to boot initially goes to grub> prompt and then via exit to initramfs, reporting it can't find scripts for local-block missing mdadm (no raid on the system). Has udev failed to populate `/dev` fully?

Other hard drives contain bootable Ubuntu 22.04, but the exact command sequence to boot the sda system is elusive.

Following boot-repair the pastebin report is at https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/HXs2PWqj9t/ and any ideas will be gratefully received.  Alternatively, how can one reinstall Ubuntu without losing the settings in `/etc`?

````
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================

modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/6.5.0-26-generic

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will purge (in order to unsign) and reinstall the grub-efi of
sde2,
using the following options:  sde1/boot sde6/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

/dev/sda3 is 97 % full

(org.gnome.Nautilus:36401): libunity-CRITICAL **: 18:07:42.946: file unity-launcher.c: line 1638: unexpected error: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory) (g-exec-error-quark, 8)

(org.gnome.Nautilus:36401): libunity-CRITICAL **: 18:07:42.947: unity_launcher_entry_dbus_impl_construct: assertion 'conn != NULL' failed

(org.gnome.Nautilus:36401): libunity-CRITICAL **: 18:07:42.950: unity-inspector.vala:96: Unable to connect to session bus: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)

(org.gnome.Nautilus:36401): dconf-WARNING **: 18:07:43.044: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)

(org.gnome.Nautilus:36401): dconf-WARNING **: 18:07:43.044: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)

** (org.gnome.Nautilus:36401): WARNING **: 18:07:43.118: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory

** (org.gnome.Nautilus:36401): WARNING **: 18:07:43.118: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory

(org.gnome.Nautilus:36401): dconf-WARNING **: 18:07:43.126: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)

** (org.gnome.Nautilus:36401): CRITICAL **: 18:07:43.140: update_dbus_opened_locations: assertion 'dbus_object_path' failed

(org.gnome.Nautilus:36401): dconf-WARNING **: 18:07:43.140: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)

** (org.gnome.Nautilus:36401): CRITICAL **: 18:08:05.433: update_dbus_opened_locations: assertion 'dbus_object_path' failed

(org.gnome.Nautilus:36401): dconf-WARNING **: 18:08:05.433: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
/dev/sde2/boot/efi not empty
apt-get -y update
Purge the GRUB of /dev/sde2
grub-efi available

0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 11 not to upgrade.
DEBCHECK debOK, grub-efi
DEBCHECK debOK
Please type: sudo dpkg --configure -ansudo apt-get install -fynsudo apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub-com*nsudo apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub2-com*nsudo apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y shim-signednsudo apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub-common:*nsudo apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub2-common:*n
Then type: sudo apt-get install -y grub-efi os-prober

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sde2/etc/default/grub

================ Reinstall the grub-efi os-prober of /dev/sde2 =================

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.06-2ubuntu7.2
modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/6.5.0-26-generic
modprobe efivars

efibootmgr -v before grub install
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0004,0007,0009,000A,0008
Boot0003* debian    HD(1,GPT,b54ba509-9eaa-464f-9108-9bc20c956a9f,0x22,0x1dcd65)/File(EFIDEBIANSHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(6,GPT,5a126de3-d8ec-48f2-b1f6-653bc549265b,0x89b82800,0xf4000)/File(EFIUBUNTUGRUBX64.EFI)
Boot0007* debian    HD(1,GPT,b54ba509-9eaa-464f-9108-9bc20c956a9f,0x22,0x1dcd65)/File(EFIDEBIANGRUBX64.EFI)..BO
Boot0008* UEFI: SanDisk, Partition 2    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/USB(2,0)/HD(2,GPT,abbd44c4-640c-4cea-acc9-ca38273f602e,0x955d78,0x2754)..BO
Boot0009* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,b1f21868-b832-460c-ba67-39cc32a6f876,0x800,0xee000)/File(EFIUBUNTUSHIMX64.EFI)..BO
Boot000A* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,b54ba509-9eaa-464f-9108-9bc20c956a9f,0x22,0x1dcd65)/File(EFIUBUNTUGRUBX64.EFI)..BO

uname -r
6.5.0-26-generic

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
Refind detected on sdd1
df /dev/sde6
mv /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
df /dev/sdd1
touch /mnt/boot-sav/sdd1/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi.grb
cp /boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sdd1/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
df /dev/sda1
mv /mnt/boot-sav/sda1/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda1/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda1/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

efibootmgr -v after grub install
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0003,0007,0008
Boot0003* debian    HD(1,GPT,b54ba509-9eaa-464f-9108-9bc20c956a9f,0x22,0x1dcd65)/File(EFIDEBIANSHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(6,GPT,5a126de3-d8ec-48f2-b1f6-653bc549265b,0x89b82800,0xf4000)/File(EFIubuntugrubx64.efi)
Boot0007* debian    HD(1,GPT,b54ba509-9eaa-464f-9108-9bc20c956a9f,0x22,0x1dcd65)/File(EFIDEBIANGRUBX64.EFI)..BO
Boot0008* UEFI: SanDisk, Partition 2    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/USB(2,0)/HD(2,GPT,abbd44c4-640c-4cea-acc9-ca38273f602e,0x955d78,0x2754)..BO

update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-26-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-25-generic
Found Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sda3
Found Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) on /dev/sdb3
Found Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) on /dev/sdd4
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sde2/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sdd4/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the The OS now in use - Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS entry (sde6/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file) !
Following some further work:
After deleting stuff like cache files, /sda3 is a lot less.  After some attempts to get sda1 to boot, it now gets to the screen showing the installed drives with operating systems. Clicking on ubuntu boots up but does not complete saying "Running /scripts/local-block... mdadm.  No devices listed in conf file were found. Gave up waiting for root file system. ALERT! /dev/sda3 does not exist. Dropping to a shell. ".  Then a note on busybox and the (initramfs) prompt.  BootRepair wants to repair a different drive. There's no raid on this system. Any thoughts/ideas?```
````

Comment: You need to resolve this first: "/dev/sda3 is 97 % full" Most desktops do not have separate /var, you probably need to manually mount that before any Boot-Repair fix or use a full chroot where yo mount all the required partitions (most may not mention mount of /var). And only use Advanced mode so you can choose install & which ESP/drive to use. You show three different ESP's in your efibootmgr -v output. https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/